# Vim 8 on Windows doesn't see plugins directory

Tags: microsoft-windows, plugin-system

I am using Vim 8.1 on Windows 10 and with a default package manager Vim doesn't see plugins in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vimfiles\pack` directory.

Did I put in into incorrect place?

**EDIT:**

It is the same configuration as I use on Ubuntu and it works there.

**EDIT 2:**

```
packpath=~/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)
\Vim\vim81,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles/after,~/vimfiles/after
```

Comment: Check output of `:set packpath?`. This shows the directories where Vim searches for a `pack` subdir.

Comment: @Ralf Please take a look on edit.

Comment: From `packpath` it seems ok. And below `...\vimfiles\pack` you have `<some-name>/start/<plugin-name>`?

Comment: @Ralf I have the following structure : `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vimfiles\pack\bundle\start\<plugins directories>`

Comment: Alex, that looks good. I don't know what could be wrong. You could try to move the `pack` directory to `~/vimfiles`.

Comment: @Ralf Do you mean `C:\Users\username\vimfiles`?

Comment: Yes. (I'm not on Windows, but that seems right.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the problem initially was in the fact that due to some issues git repo files cloned in Ubuntu subsystem wasn't visible to Windows.

The second thing: paths should be `HOME/vimfiles` and `HOME/.vimrc`. At least this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if packages are being searched in `$VIM/vimfiles` directory.

Try

1. if your `HOME` environment variable is not set, set it. (right click on Start button, select `System`, then `Advanced system settings`, then `Environment Variables`
2. put your `vimfiles` directory to `HOME`

It works for me, settings and packages are loaded etc...

Comment: Setting `HOME` didn't help, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how your directory structure below `pack` should look like:

```
pack
└── bundle
    ├── opt
    │   └── vim-fugitive
    │       ├── autoload
    │       ├── doc
    │       ├── ftdetect
    │       ├── plugin
    │       └── syntax
    └── start
        ├── ctrlp.vim
        │   ├── autoload
        │   │   └── ctrlp
        │   ├── doc
        │   └── plugin
        └── vim-commentary
            ├── doc
            └── plugin
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have the same on my linux machine and it works, so that's why I am surprised that on Windows it doesn't work.